# Add progress bar value to the center of the Progress bar elements

Tags: javascript, css, progress-bar

I have a few progress bars which are generated dynamically based on the rest service api.
How do i add the value at the centre of the progress bar as in the video with plain CSS and JS (without jquery or other libraries)

Code
https://jsbin.com/wozeqaw/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<title>Optus FrontEnd Assignment</title>


  <style>
            .wrapper {
                width: 500px;
            }
            
            .progress-bar {
                background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
    position: relative;
            }
            
            .progress-bar-fill {
                display: block;
                height: 22px;
                background-color: #659cef;
                border-radius: 3px;
                
                transition: width 500ms ease-in-out;
            }
        </style>

</head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet">

<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                //Use parse() method to convert JSON string to JSON object
                var responseJsonObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                // console.log(responseJsonObj);

                for (let p = 0; p < responseJsonObj.bars.length; p++) {
                    //Create Progress Bars
                    var Progressbar = document.createElement("PROGRESS");
                  Progressbar.className = 'progress-bar';
                    var idTag = "Progress" + p.toString();
                    Progressbar.setAttribute("id", idTag);
                    Progressbar.setAttribute("value", responseJsonObj.bars[p]);
                    Progressbar.setAttribute("max", responseJsonObj.limit);
                    var br = document.createElement("br");
                    document.body.appendChild(Progressbar);
                    document.body.appendChild(br);
                }

                //Create Drop Down
                var Select = document.createElement("SELECT");
                Select.setAttribute("id", "selectElement");
                document.body.appendChild(Select);
                var opt = null;
                for (o = 0; o < responseJsonObj.bars.length; o++) {
                    // alert(o);
                    opt = document.createElement('option');
                    opt.value = "Progress" + o;
                    opt.innerHTML = "#Progress" + o;
                    Select.appendChild(opt);
                }
                for (let b = 0; b < responseJsonObj.buttons.length; b++) {
                    //Create Buttons
                    var Button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
                    Button.innerHTML = responseJsonObj.buttons[b];
                    Button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                        //Button Event handling
                        var selected_PB_Element = document.getElementById("selectElement");
                        var selected_PB_Value = selected_PB_Element.value;
                        debugger;

                        document.getElementById(selected_PB_Value).value = document.getElementById(selected_PB_Value).value + responseJsonObj.buttons[b];
                        //alert(selected_PB_Value);
                        // alert(responseJsonObj.buttons[b]);
                        console.log(responseJsonObj.buttons[b]);
                    });
                    document.body.appendChild(Button);
                }
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://pb-api.herokuapp.com/bars", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    </script>

    <div class="w3-container">
        <h2>Progress Bars Demo</h2>
    </div>
    <br>

</body>
```

Expected output

[image]

Comment: If you're OK with it not being perfectly centered this will work: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_progressbar.asp

Comment: I need to be perfectly centered to the progress bar.

Comment: I think you can do it with 2 divs and using z-index. Bottom (0) would be the div the length of your completed progress bar and the completed % as text centered. Top would be a div that is the width of your completed progress. Article on using z-index to stack divs here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/z-index-explained-how-to-stack-elements-using-css-7c5aa0f179b3/

Comment: I did an example. Glad if it helps you. https://codepen.io/dshung1997/pen/ExypZqK

Comment: would it be possible to edit the code  https://jsbin.com/wozeqaw/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses CSS Grid to make it so both the progress-bar and the value are in the same cell of the grid so they overlap without any weird positioning.

Comments are in the code, and https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/ was used to help with some of the styling of the progress bar.

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    //Use parse() method to convert JSON string to JSON object
    var responseJsonObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    // console.log(responseJsonObj);

    for (let p = 0; p < responseJsonObj.bars.length; p++) {
      //Create Progress Bars
      // Create a wrapper div
      var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
      wrapper.className = 'wrapper';
      var Progressbar = document.createElement('PROGRESS');
      Progressbar.className = 'progress-bar';
      var idTag = 'Progress' + p.toString();
      Progressbar.setAttribute('id', idTag);
      Progressbar.setAttribute('value', responseJsonObj.bars[p]);
      Progressbar.setAttribute('max', responseJsonObj.limit);
      // Make sure to change the color on start if needed!
      changeColors(Progressbar);
      // add progress bar to wrapper
      wrapper.appendChild(Progressbar);
      //Create a span to contain the number
      var number = document.createElement('span');
      number.innerText = responseJsonObj.bars[p];
      // add number span to wrapper
      wrapper.appendChild(number);
      var br = document.createElement('br');
      // add wrapper to document.
      document.body.appendChild(wrapper);
      document.body.appendChild(br);
    }

    //Create Drop Down
    var Select = document.createElement('SELECT');
    Select.setAttribute('id', 'selectElement');
    document.body.appendChild(Select);
    var opt = null;
    for (o = 0; o < responseJsonObj.bars.length; o++) {
      // alert(o);
      opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.value = 'Progress' + o;
      opt.innerHTML = '#Progress' + o;
      Select.appendChild(opt);
    }
    for (let b = 0; b < responseJsonObj.buttons.length; b++) {
      //Create Buttons
      var Button = document.createElement('BUTTON');
      Button.innerHTML = responseJsonObj.buttons[b];
      Button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        //Button Event handling
        var selected_PB_Element = document.getElementById(
          'selectElement'
        );
        var selected_PB_Value = selected_PB_Element.value;
        let currentNode = document.getElementById(selected_PB_Value);

        // Get the next sibling ( the number span)
        let nextSibling = currentNode.nextElementSibling;
        currentNode.value +=
          responseJsonObj.buttons[b];

        // Also set the text of the number span
        nextSibling.innerText = currentNode.value;

        changeColors(currentNode);

      });
      document.body.appendChild(Button);
    }
  }
};

function changeColors(progressNode) {
  const {
    value,
    max
  } = progressNode;

  // If value is greater than a certain amount, set a class
  // otherwise remove that class - Can do ranges of values here.
  if (value >= .75 * max) {
    progressNode.classList.add('green');
  } else {
    progressNode.classList.remove('green');
  }
}
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'http://pb-api.herokuapp.com/bars', true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  /* make the text centered vertically and horizontally in the cell */
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper>* {
  /* All children of the wrapper should share the same grid area! */
  grid-area: 1 / 1;
}

.progress-bar {
  /* Make the progress bar expand to fill the whole cell */
  width: 100%;
  /* Make it a tad taller - Could make this 100% as well and set the height in the wrapper */
  height: 30px;
}


/* Attempt to get the appearances to look like the example */

.progress-bar {
  /* Reset the default appearance */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid #cccbcd;
}


/* These will only work on safari/chromium */

progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  /*   box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset; */
}

progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
  /*    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset; */
  background-color: #b2d7e6;
}


/* -moz-progress-bar changes the color of the filled part - REALLY inconsistent here */

progress[value]::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color: #b2d7e6;
  border-radius: 2px;
  /*   box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset; */
}


/* Make the bar green */

progress[value].green::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

progress[value].green::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Optus FrontEnd Assignment</title>
</head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <div class="w3-container">
    <h2>Progress Bars Demo</h2>
  </div>
  <br />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: whats the recommended approach to change the progress bar color after a certain value ?

Comment: @smith006 I added what you asked for. The main thing with that is just to set a class at the certain points you want to, then style the bar based on the class in the css.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the progress bar in a div and add a label.

Set the container to be relative position and the label to be absolute and center the text by setting top, left and transform parameters.

Make the progress bar 100% the size of the container and the label will center over the progress bar.

```
<html><head>
    <style>

        .bar-container {
            position: relative;
            padding: 5px;
            height: 40px;
            width: 400px;
        }

        .prog-bar {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            appearance: none;
        }

        .prog-label {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
    </style>
    
    </head>
    <body>    
    </body>
    <script>

        const apiData = {"buttons":[5,47,-45,-22],"bars":[66,48,49,65],"limit":160};

        function progValue(container, val){
            const bar = container.getElementsByClassName('prog-bar')[0];
            const label = container.getElementsByClassName('prog-label')[0];

            const max = parseInt(bar.getAttribute('max'));
            const oldVal = parseInt(bar.getAttribute('value'));
            const newVal = Math.min(Math.max(oldVal + val, 0), max);

            bar.setAttribute('value', newVal);
            const percent = (newVal / max) * 100;
            label.innerHTML = percent.toFixed(0) + '%';            
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < apiData.bars.length; i++) {
            const val = apiData.bars[i];

            const container = document.createElement('div');
            container.setAttribute('class', 'bar-container');
            container.setAttribute('id', 'Progress' + i);

            const progress = document.createElement('progress');            
            progress.setAttribute('class', 'prog-bar');
            progress.setAttribute('value', 0);
            progress.setAttribute('max', apiData.limit);

            const label = document.createElement('label');
            label.setAttribute('class', 'prog-label');

            container.appendChild(progress);
            container.appendChild(label);
            document.body.appendChild(container);

            progValue(container, val);
        }

        const select = document.createElement('select');
        select.setAttribute('id', 'barSelector');
        for (let bar of document.getElementsByClassName('bar-container')) {
            const opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.text = bar.getAttribute('id');
            opt.innerHTML = bar.getAttribute('id');
            select.appendChild(opt);
        }
        document.body.appendChild(select);

        for(let butVal of apiData.buttons) {
            const button = document.createElement('button');
            button.innerHTML = butVal;
            button.addEventListener('click', event => {
                const select = document.getElementById('barSelector');
                const val = select.value;

                const container = document.getElementById(val);

                if(container) {
                    progValue(container, butVal);
                }
            });
            document.body.appendChild(button);
        }

    </script>
</html>
```